# EXC_ARITHMETIC Error Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

```
#import "Calculator.h"

@implementation Calculator

- (long) calcNumbers:(NSString *)myOperator andNumberOne:(NSString *)numberOne andNumberTwo:(NSString *)numberTwo {

    long result;

    if ([myOperator isEqualToString:@"+"]){
        result = [numberOne integerValue] + [numberTwo integerValue];
    } else if ([myOperator isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
        result = [numberOne integerValue] - [numberTwo integerValue];
    } else if ([myOperator isEqualToString:@"*"]){
        result = [numberOne integerValue] * [numberTwo integerValue];
    } else if ([myOperator isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
        result = [numberOne integerValue] / [numberTwo integerValue];
    } else {
        result = [numberOne integerValue] % [numberTwo integerValue];
    }

    return result;

}


- (long) postFix:(NSMutableArray *)symbols
{

    NSMutableArray * newSymbols = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString * operatorSigns    = @"*/%";
    long result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.count; i++){

        // operand
        if (i%2 == 0){
            [newSymbols addObject:symbols[i]];
        } else { // operator

            if ([operatorSigns containsString:symbols[i]]){
                result = [self calcNumbers:symbols[i] andNumberOne:symbols[i-1] andNumberTwo:symbols[i+1]];
                [newSymbols insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:result] atIndex:i-1];
                i = i + 1;
            } else {
                [newSymbols addObject:symbols[i]];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newSymbols.count; i++){
        if (i%2 == 1){
            result = [self calcNumbers:newSymbols[i] andNumberOne:newSymbols[i-1] andNumberTwo:newSymbols[i+1]];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

This is my class. I am trying to run RPN calculator in command line. But in calcNumbers method, there is EXC_Arithmetic error. I think asterisk is working as (all) unix_command. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: That error probably means that you are dividing by zero (`/` or `%` operators). You have to solve that case.

Comment: Please, add the input for the `postFix` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you are doing now in `postFix` is correct, I don't even know what you are trying to do.

The crash happens because you are sending bad values to `calcNumbers`. By bad values I mean values in unexpected order.

For example, if `myOperator` is `@"10"` and `numberTwo` is `*`, then you will enter the `else` branch:

```
 result = [numberOne integerValue] % [numberTwo integerValue];
```

and you will be dividing (calculating modulo) by zero, which will cause the crash (you cannot divide by zero).

How to find the problem (not an actual solution):

Add

```
NSLog(@"Operator %@, operands: %@, %@", myOperator, numberOne, numberTwo);
```

That should help you see what values are passed to your function and find the problem.